# How to merge two rows in a dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with two rows and I'd like to merge the two rows to one row. 
The df Looks as follows:

```
              PC           Rating CY   Rating PY    HT
0             DE101           NaN            AA     GV
0             DE101           AA+           NaN     GV
```

I have tried to create two seperate dataframes and Combine them with df.merge(df2) without success. The result should be the following

```
              PC           Rating CY   Rating PY    HT
0             DE101           AA+            AA     GV
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance
Could df.update be a possible solution?

EDIT:

```
df.head(1).combine_first(df.tail(1))
```

This works for the example above. However, for columns containing numerical values, this approach doesn't yield the desired output, e.g. for

```
              PC           Rating CY   Rating PY    HT    MV1   MV2
0             DE101           NaN            AA     GV    0     20 
0             DE101           AA+           NaN     GV    10    0
```

The output should be:

```
              PC           Rating CY   Rating PY    HT   MV1    MV2
0             DE101           AA+            AA     GV   10     20
```

The formula above doesn't sum up the values in the last two columns, but takes the values in the first row of the dataframe.

```
              PC           Rating CY   Rating PY    HT   MV1    MV2
0             DE101           AA+            AA     GV   0     20
```

How could this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [`DF.combine_first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method after separating the `DF` into 2 parts where the null values in the first half would be replaced with the finite values in the other half while keeping it's other finite values untouched:

```
df.head(1).combine_first(df.tail(1))
# Practically this is same as → df.head(1).fillna(df.tail(1))
```

[image]

---

Incase there are columns of mixed datatype, partitioning them into it's constituent `dtype` columns and then performing various operations on it would be feasible by chaining them across.

```
obj_df = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.object])
num_df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.object])

obj_df.head(1).combine_first(obj_df.tail(1)).join(num_df.head(1).add(num_df.tail(1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works for the example above. However, if there are additional columns with numerical values, the rows can't be combined properly, see edit of my post

Comment: I've updated my post. Since you hadn't mentioned the presence of numerical values in your dataframe, I assumed you wanted to just update the top row with the bottom one in case of any nulls found.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Another way would be replacing the 0 values in the last two columns by NaN and then apply the first forumla you suggested

Answer (score 8):

You could use `max` with transpose like

```
In [2103]: df.max().to_frame().T
Out[2103]:
      PC Rating CY Rating PY  HT MV1 MV2
0  DE101       AA+        AA  GV  10  20
```