# Combining rows in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my original DF in pandas.

[image: Dataframe]

I've tried to combine the first 5 rows into one row by using:
**combine_first**, but I can't achieve it.

[image: I want this]

Also I've followed this answer: [How to merge two rows in a dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693000/how-to-merge-two-rows-in-a-dataframe-pandas). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***option 1***
`pd.DataFrame.bfill`

```
df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
```

***option 2***
`pd.DataFrame.lookup`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.lookup(df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index), df.columns),
    df.columns).T
```

***option 3***
`numpy.argmax`

```
v = df.values
pd.DataFrame(
    v[(~np.isnan(v)).argmax(0), np.arange(v.shape[1])].reshape(1, -1),
    columns=df.columns)
```

---

All yield

[image]

---

***time testing***

[image]