# Merging Two Rows (one with a value, the other NaN) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware similar questions have been asked before ([How to merge two rows in a dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693000/how-to-merge-two-rows-in-a-dataframe-pandas), etc), but I am still struggling to do the following (except with pandas dataframe with many rows):

```
    team_token  day1    day2   day3  day4
0   abc          1      NaN     NaN   NaN
1   abc          NaN     1      NaN   NaN
2   abc          NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN
3   abc          NaN     NaN    NaN     1
```

I want to combine the rows with the same team_token so that the end result looks like:

```
    team_token  day1    day2  day3  day4
0   abc           1      1    NaN     1
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: put your code, what you have tried yet @cgp25

Comment: I tried df.combine_first, but to no avail

Comment: you want to remove NaN values?

Comment: No, they can remain @HardikSondagar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) on two `Series` given by the two rows of you dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'team_token':['abc', 'abc'], 'day1': [1, None], 'day2' : [None, 1]})

df.loc[0].combine_first(df.loc[1])
```

gives:

```
 team_token  day1    day2
0   abc           1       1
```

#EDIT:
A better solution that works also with your updated answer is simply:

```
df.max()
```

assuming that your `day` columns contain either Nan or ones.

In case you have different `team_tokens`:

```
   day1  day2  day3 team_token
0   1.0   NaN   NaN        abc
1   NaN   NaN   NaN        abc
2   1.0   1.0   NaN        abc
3   NaN   NaN   NaN        abc
4   1.0   NaN   1.0        ddd
5   1.0   NaN   1.0        ddd
6   NaN   NaN   1.0        ddd
```

you can `group_by` and still take the `max` of the group:

```
df.groupby('team_token').max().reset_index()

#  team_token  day1  day2  day3
#0        abc   1.0   1.0   NaN
#1        ddd   1.0   NaN   1.0
```

Comment: I will try! I realize now my 1s are actually strings, so will fix and try the above, which should work! Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one non-NaN value for each team_token, you can use groupby/sum

```
df.groupby('team_token')['day1', 'day2'].sum().reset_index()
```

You get

```
    team_token  day1    day2
0   abc         1.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, not the shortest solution, but imho more flexible.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'team_token':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc'], 
                   'day1': [1, None, None, None], 
                   'day2': [None, 1, None, None],
                   'day3': [None, None, None, None],
                   'day4': [None, None, None, 1]})
df
```

[image]

```
def replace_nan_func(x):
    x = x[~pd.isna(x)]
    if len(x) > 0:
        return x.iloc[0]
    else:
        return np.NaN

df_valid = df.groupby(by='team_token').agg(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[1:], replace_nan_func))
df_valid
```

[image]