# pandas merge header rows if one is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm importing into a dataframe an excel sheet which has its headers split into two rows:

```
Colour | NaN   | Shape | Mass | NaN
NaN    | width | NaN   | NaN  | Torque

green  | 33    | round | 2    | 6
etc
```

I want to collapse the first two rows into one header:

```
Colour | width | Shape | Mass | Torque

green  | 33    | round | 2    | 6
...
```

I tried `merged_header = df.loc[0].combine_first(df.loc[1])`
but I'm not sure how to get that back into the original dataframe.

I've tried:

```py
# drop top 2 rows
df = df.drop(df.index[[0,1]])
# then add the merged one in:
res = pd.concat([merged_header, df], axis=0)
```

But that just inserts `merged_header` as a column.  I tried some other combinations of `merge` from [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-merging-joining-and-concatenating/) but without luck.

`merged_header.append(df)` gives a similar wrong result, and `res = df.append(merged_header)` is almost right, but the header is at the tail end:

```
green  | 33    | round | 2    | 6
...
Colour | width | Shape | Mass | Torque
```

To provide more detail this is what I have so far:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(ltro19, header=None, skiprows=9)
# delete all empty columns & rows
df = df.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
```

in case if affects the next step.

Comment: Is it just 5 columns you have?

Comment: ('cos a quick although not generic way to do it would be `df = pd.read_excel('filename', skiprows=2, header=None, names=['colour', 'width', 'shape', 'mass', 'torque'])`...

Comment: @JonClements, no. I have 20 columns with very long titles, and many excel sheets (equally formatted but with other headers).  It was just a simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to my ignorance of the terms, the suggestions above did not lead me directly to a working solution. It seemed I was working with a dataframe

```
>>> print(type(df))
>>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

but, I think, without headers.

This solution worked, although it involved jumping out of the dataframe and into a list to then put it back as the column headers.  Inspired by [Merging Two Rows (one with a value, the other NaN) in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44799264/)

```py
df = pd.read_excel(name_of_file, header=None, skiprows=9)
# delete all empty columns & rows
df = df.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')

# merge the two headers which are weirdly split over two rows
merged_header = df.loc[0].combine_first(df.loc[1])
# turn that into a list
header_list = merged_header.values.tolist()
# load that list as the new headers for the dataframe
df.columns = header_list
# drop top 2 rows (old split header)
df = df.drop(df.index[[0,1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use list comprehension to flatten multiindex column header:

```
df.columns = [f'{j}' if str(i)=='nan' else f'{i}' for i, j in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
['Colour', 'width', 'Shape', 'Mass', 'Torque']
```

Comment: `df.columns` is `Int64Index([0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25], dtype='int64')`, so iterating over it leads to `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Then you do don't have a multiIndex colum headers.  You just need to move the first two rows of your dataframe into column header.

Comment: You need to create code that will produce your input dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't have the right vocabulary yet. I don't know what a multiIndex dataframe is.  All I have is an excel sheet with very strange formatting and I'm trying to turn it into a more reasonable table.  Where can I learn about "moving rows into column header"? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df.columns = list(df.columns.get_level_values(0))
```

Comment: `df.columns.get_level_values(0)` returns `Int64Index([0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25], dtype='int64')` but calling list on it gives the error `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`